# What is the right pattern for accessing a C# DLL from C++?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, c++-cli, windows-phone-8.1

I generally work on Android/Java, but right now I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1. I have C++ code in a library that needs to be able to access the functionality in a provided C# Assembly DLL.

The C# DLL has an interfaces that needs to be implemented to receive callbacks from the DLL.

What I've tried:

1. I tried using a Windows Runtime Component to wrap around the DLL , but then it complains that the interface isn't valid to use with Windows Runtime Components.
2. I can wrap the DLL in a pile of C# code, and provide an interface in that to forward on any callbacks from the DLL to any implementation (C++), but the C++ code doesn't want to recognize the namespace as an existing namespace.

What is the missing piece?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: Windows Runtime Component is unavailable?

Comment: @Eddie I can make a Windows Runtime Component to call into the provided DLL, but I can't use it to implement the callback interfaces defined in the DLL, the compiler complains that they can't be used in the Windows Runtime layer. I believe that's because of the types referenced as arguments and return types in the interface signatures.

Comment: Maybe you have to wrap your callback interfaces in C++/CX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the DLL using a C# Windows Runtime Component. The callback interfaces from the DLL were implemented in C# and would call back into the C# Windows Runtime Component to do work.

The work to be done was calling a C++ Windows Runtime Component that would do the talking to the C# Windows Runtime Component. The C++ Windows Runtime Component could then be the gateway to the C++ library of code we have.

Answer (score -1):

The C++/C# interoperability can be achieved in two ways: through Win32 DLLs or through COM components.

If you plan to use the Win32 approach you're gonna have to provide all the metadata in terms of CLR types, then the managed compiler will compile the metadata into the assembly and the JIT compiler will build stubs that performs the C#/Win32 conversion.

If you plan to use the COM components you'll have to use the Runtime Callable Wrappers, that will take care of instantiation, type navigation, error handling and memory management.

More information about RCW is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer.